# Rename a string-array in arrays.xml

Tags: android

In my values/arrays.xml, I have  `<string-array name="pref_entries" translatable="false">`
but as soon as I rename it to

```
<string-array name="pref_entries2" translatable="false">
```

I get this error:

res/values/arrays.xml:28: error: Resource at pref_entries appears in overlay but not in the base package; use  to add.

Can you please tell me how can I fix my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: There is another array `pref_entries` somewhere in some code that confuses your build. Don't know how to fix but the only place I've seen overlays is like [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-framework/browse_thread/thread/e9974bd5a42af10a)

Comment: I have 'grep for pref_entries in my project, but I don' see any where other than R.java

Comment: You may need to clean the project. If a resource exists in R then eiher R is outdated or the resource exists somewhere since R is just generated from those